# Want to show the label in a particular condition

Tags: reactjs

I want show the label when username already exists..What condition I need to apply.. Here is my code.

```
handleCheck = () => {
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
        this.props.checkUser(values,this.props.companyId);
    });
    this.setState({checkFlag:true});
};

<Col span={12} >
    <FormItem>
        {getFieldDecorator('UserName', {
            initialValue: "",
            rules: [{
                required: true, message: 'Please Input your UserName!',
            }],
        })(                                
            <Input placeholder="UserName" onChange={this.handleCheck} />              
        )}
    </FormItem>
</Col> 

{(here condition)?
    <label for="test" style={{"color":"red","paddingLeft":"54%","fontSize":"13px"}}>Username already exists</label>:''
}
```

Comment: show your `this.handleCheck` please!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this function `this.props.checkUser` is returning true or false.

Change your handleCheck function to

```
handleCheck = () => {
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
       let isUserExist = this.props.checkUser(values,this.props.companyId);
        this.setState({checkFlag:isUserExist});
    });
};
```

JSX changes

```
{this.checkFlag && 
    <label for="test" style="color:red;paddingLeft:54%;fontSize:13px">Username already exists</label>}
```